# Adding arbitrary angle to `atan2` result

Tags: trigonometry

`atan2(y, x)` returns by default directions between $-\pi$ and $\pi$ with $0$ being east. Is there an easy way to add/shift/rotate the direction of 0. For example, I would like to say 0 is north-west.

Comment: Take the angle that `atan2` returns for northwest and subtract it. If you want to keep the result within $\pm\pi$, then add/subtract $2\pi$ when it is out of range.

Comment: How about you make that an answer? If someone finds something wrong with it, then they can just comment below.